# Get n numbers from a range, including x

Tags: python

I am creating a pagination system in python. I have a given range of pages [1, ... n] and want to extract exactly m numbers from it, including current page number. When this is possible, the current page number has to be in the center. Is there any elegant way to do this?

I know it can be done using few if...else statements, but this seems very clumsy.

```py
def generate_short_page_range(current_page, page_range, shown_pages_number):
    pages_on_one_side = int((shown_pages_number - 1) / 2)
    short_page_range = range(current_page - pages_on_one_side, current_page + pages_on_one_side + 1)

    # creating common part of page ranges
    short_page_range = [item for item in short_page_range if item in page_range]

    return short_page_range
```

For data: current_page=1, page_range size>=7 and shown_pages_number=7 I want to return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], right now it returns [1, 2, 3, 4]

**EDIT:**
Let's say that I have list of 20 pages, which gives us page range that looks like this: [1, 2, ... 19, 20]. I want to limit paginator size to e.g. 5 pages, so when we are on page 12 it shows [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]. But I also want it to **always** show exactly 5 pages, so when there is only one page to the left from current one, I want it to show additional one on the right side. So when we are on page 2, I want to return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4] which I would get from my current function. Same for the first page, I want to return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] instead of [1, 2, 3]

Comment: What do you mean by `page_range >= 7`? It would be good if you can give a few examples of the input structure and the intended output structure, because currently the description seems a bit vague to me and I don't know what arguments to pass to your function to get the output `[1,2,3,4]` you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution uses if-else too, I think that is the most straight forward way:

```
def generate_short_page_range(current_page, page_range, shown_pages_number):

    page_per_side = shown_pages_number // 2
    current_page_index = page_range.index(current_page)

    # First, check if the current_page is at the edges
    if current_page in page_range[page_per_side:-page_per_side]:
        return page_range[current_page_index - page_per_side : current_page_index + page_per_side + shown_pages_number%2]

    # If it is at the front, return the firstfew pages (len = shown_pages_number)
    elif current_page_index < len(page_range) // 2:
        return page_range[:shown_pages_number]

    # If it is at the end, return the last few pages (len = shown_pages_number)
    else:
        return page_range[-shown_pages_number:]
```

Run a simple test:

```
# test 
page_range = [num for num in range(22,30)]
shown_pages_number = 5

for page in page_range:
    print(f'Page {page}:')
    print(generate_short_page_range(page, page_range, shown_pages_number))
```

Output:

```
Page 22:
[22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
Page 23:
[22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
Page 24:
[22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
Page 25:
[23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
Page 26:
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
Page 27:
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Page 28:
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Page 29:
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```